# C# Forms Combobox no se actualiza Capa presentacion

Tags: c#, sql, windows-forms, combobox

Buen día,

Tengo un problema al cargar información en un Combobox en mi aplicación de ventas, se utiliza una base de datos SQL local utilizando procesos almacenados, en base el proceso almacenado, el programa debe verificar una selección de un Combobox (Este siendo Categoría) y mostrar las opciones correspondientes de "Categoría" en "Nombre" (Este siendo el nombre del producto a buscar) a la hora de correr el programa el Combobox de "Categoría" funciona perfectamente mientras que el de "Nombre" no muestra ningún dato, si llego a cambiar de "Área de venta" como se mira en las fotos el programa muestra los datos como se debe, pienso yo que el problema se encuentra a la hora de actualizar los datos sin cambiar de "Área de venta" sin embargo no logro hacer que este cambie sin necesidad de cambiar de ventanilla. Aqui esta el codigo de la capa de presentacion en donde se presenta el problema (En el metodo ComboboxNombreL)

```
{
    public partial class Venta : Form
    {

        public Venta()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ComboboxCategoriaL()
        {
            try
            {
                CN_Ventas inventario = new CN_Ventas();
                DataTable dt;
                dt = inventario.ObCategoriaL();
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    CbCategoriaL.Items.Add(dr["Categoria"].ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No se ha podido cargar la base de datos");
            }
        }

        private void ComboboxNombreL()
        {
            try
            {
                CN_Ventas inventario = new CN_Ventas();
                DataTable dt;
                if (CbCategoriaL.Text != "")
                { 
                    dt = inventario.OBNombreL(CbCategoriaL.Text);
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        CbNombreL.Items.Add(dr["Nombre"].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("No se ha podido cargar la base de datos");
            }
        }

    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Proceso almacenado:
Create proc [dbo].[VentasCbNombreL]
@Categoria VARCHAR (100)
as
Begin
select distinct Nombre from Inventario where Inventario.Categoria = @Categoria
Return
END**

Answer (score 0):

puedes simplificar tu llenado de combobox de esta manera

```
private void ComboboxCategoriaL()
    {
        try
        {
            CN_Ventas inventario = new CN_Ventas();
            DataTable dt;
            dt = inventario.ObCategoriaL();
            CbCategoriaL.DataSource = dt;
            CbCategoriaL.DisplayMember = "Categoria";
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No se ha podido cargar la base de datos");
        }
    }
```

En donde al combobox a su propiedad datasource(origen de datos) le asignas el datatable, y utilizas la propiedad DisplayMember del combo asignandole el nombre de la columna que deseas mostrar.

Espero te sea de ayuda.